# Check if mail was encrypted between servers using the header?

Tags: encryption, tls, email

I am trying to read the email header and see if the emails is encrypted during transit.
By looking at the lines from email header `Received: by 2002:a6b:e40f:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP`  and `Received: by mx.google.com with SMTP`, Can I say that both intermediate servers receives the email unencrypted? As they didn't used SMTPS.

```
Delivered-To: tarun14110@iiitd.ac.in
Received: by 2002:a6b:e40f:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id u15-v6csp802696iog;
        Tue, 5 Jun 2018 04:29:16 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ADUXVKK7FmuEdykDBKIk7o8L+bRVG61fxOU7BPx1gPCI3ULrpsybhuZOJk7BnCx2p9EGAr7cJhBO
X-Received: by 2002:a62:9e0b:: with SMTP id s11-v6mr25257897pfd.198.1528198156817;
        Tue, 05 Jun 2018 04:29:16 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1528198156; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=aXdq6nelhyXPJLW8I9Qi96Rc/+Mh30JVoXuBM7F7F4bLzP/XirI6nsl+C7t854ivn6
         +L2LVe5d54RvKbBe3Nz/OoSxG4cNudZCuHz4BqXfOFgYiEhq5DLj1VEayCu+b1K4mzLJ
         9d6IYeEDSfn+35lPOdViWiT4mFE7uFKAONa9NyCq/GhYJm57ipFuzZv4qVUbL3BNLwoC
         bOffBk1trUJKVkV3j0D+DwKM6C0HXWoQ5UYP1zHXKsaGrCu40BMhCFb8AApN+2Z57p7R
         1VQSyT3uQP3l6E3qeysZkUUxgy9xpqiVTSbyK9o+y9vLrvqFVXKYhwcHhxNftNG/FPW8
         orlg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=format:bounce_header:mime-version:subject:message-id:to:from:date
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=9VKxJ5Cey9zw5v070mGRSg40T9KP30Hmpi0K4VH5lSo=;
        b=jrSDIsxGPVuVJAfMJD9muiH96TupmyTr0RnLu+YQLcdzcZnhnFentj0086bvAXRaNt
         8ytb9D2LLS60pm/rRi4V9xDGXd/eyGNZw+/hSC66XY+gUk71z7HUA80AYc/vz4a3RpAr
         KV0eGM4Po6QSTAbYGkoQqz8HUdRrTCbkv5/WAVNzNwc83cGwmSuznevgo2HnaSryoupQ
         whsdGATYJVHiDFN4IuXwPMpGK1Cq9Y/7zAa/wAcSrl5Dm424vG8PJ9ArRmN4nVv5R2Ap
         QhtdF2LqO9xV5Xh5O7sTX48yTKOKuk1b+Z0pV6giVuEvymHEOoBdWR5D63H/kq8GMH+6
         l4Ug==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of notification@jio.com designates 49.40.2.101 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=Notification@jio.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=jio.com
Return-Path: <Notification@jio.com>
Received: from smtp-outgoing.mail.rjil.net (smtp-outgoing.mail.rjil.net. [49.40.2.101])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id b2-v6si8841616plz.118.2018.06.05.04.29.15
        for <tarun14110@iiitd.ac.in>;
        Tue, 05 Jun 2018 04:29:16 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of notification@jio.com designates 49.40.2.101 as permitted sender) client-ip=49.40.2.101;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of notification@jio.com designates 49.40.2.101 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=Notification@jio.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=jio.com
Date: Tue, 05 Jun 2018 04:29:16 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from NVMBD2ANO130V15.bss.jio.com (unknown [10.140.84.156]) by smtp-outgoing.mail.rjil.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 5AC484007A for <tarun14110@iiitd.ac.in>; Tue,
  5 Jun 2018 16:59:15 +0530 (IST)
Received: from NVMBD2BKT10D00 (prdin10sneapp12.bss.jio.com [10.143.71.24]) by NVMBD2ANO130V15.bss.jio.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 588E444003F for <tarun14110@iiitd.ac.in>; Tue,
  5 Jun 2018 16:59:15 +0530 (IST)
From: Notification@jio.com
To: tarun14110@iiitd.ac.in
Message-ID: <332909303.95975672.1528198155363.JavaMail.mwapp@NVMBD2BKT10D00>
Subject: 50% of Daily Data quota exhausted for Jio Number 7982839625
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_95975667_1604714169.1528198155359"
Bounce_Header: 6314899050863033344
format: flowed
```

All the emails I received have their header starting with the below line.

```
Delivered-To: tarun14110@iiitd.ac.in
Received: by 2002:a6b:e40f:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id
```

Does this means, that the last hop always recieves email unencrypted?

Comment: In short: nothing in the Received headers in your mail indicates that the mail was transferred with TLS - but it might still have been done since the MTA is not required to add this information. Most MTA do though, which means it was likely not transferred with TLS.